# A version of Arzelà–Ascoli theorem concerning normal family

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, arzela-ascoli

In [this document](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~chen418/study_research/Montel-Theorem.pdf), the following theorem is given:

> **Theorem 2.1 (Arzela-Ascoli).** A subfamily $\mathcal F \subseteq C(U)$ is normal iff it is
>   both equicontinuous and pointwise bounded.

Here, $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ is an open set, and $C(U)$ is the family of continuous functions defined on $U$.

I suspect that the statement of the theorem is not entirely accurate. After all, if $\mathcal F=(f_n)$, where $f_n$ converges uniformly to $\infty$ on $U$, then $\mathcal F$ is a normal family, but it is in no way pointwise bounded.

How could I correct the statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Montel Great theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353915/montel-great-theorem)

Comment: In your example $f_n \to \infty$ the limit function is not in $C(U)$, and you have to consider the functions $U \to \hat{\Bbb C}$ with the spherical metric instead.

Comment: @MartinR But why must the limit exist in $C(U)$?

Comment: @MartinR So, you mean that the "tends uniformly to infinity" part in the definition of normal family should be deleted if we use the Euclidean metric?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.